# getting contact id after saving android contact

Tags: android, contacts

I am saving a contact by this code

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops =
          new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
 ...
 int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();
 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
          .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType)
          .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName)
          .build());

 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
          .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
          .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
          .withValue(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, linkname1)
          .withValue(StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, linkname2)
          .build());

 getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

After saving the contact, I need to get the _ID field so that I can fetch that contact from the contact book for editing. How can I get the id after saving?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ContentProviderResult[] res = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);

Uri myContactUri = res[0].uri;
int contactID = Integer.parseInt(myContactUri.getLastPathSegment());
```

Comment: Through your answer i am able to get contactId but when i compared with Contacts._ID , there is difference in value.Does above one is raw contact id?

Comment: Here above "contactID" is actually ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID, so we/you need to fetch desired Contact table's ID using ContentResolver Query.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Get the contact id for the number( ´phnumber` ) from the contacts

```
String[] projection = new String[]{Contacts._ID};
Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,Uri.encode(phnumber));
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection,
  null, null, null);
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
long contactId=c.getColumnIndex(Contacts._ID);


c.close();

}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. what is the phnumber and how can I get it?

Comment: phnumber is your contact number you have added.